# Can closure be used in place of webpack and rollupjs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, google-closure-compiler, rollupjs

I'm planning on publishing a library written in typescript for the browser that uses the Node streaming API.  IIUC I should compile it to ES6 module providing the ES6 exports and expose it via `package.json` as `module: index.js`, as an ideal target for closure?

Would that be correct?  Can the closure compiler then be used in place of webpack and rollupjs?

So the end goal would be:

1) `npm install the-package`

2) import {1-function-out-of-10-functions} from the-package

3) run through closure build

Done it now works in the browser (And it's more optimized than what webpack and rollupjs would provide)?

Comment: The question in the body seems a bit different from the title.  You're basically asking how to package an ES6 module, compiled from Typescript, which runs in the browser, as an NPM module which you can publish?  If that's your question, typical practice is to provide both a module which you can `import` or `require()` from Node (and therefore Browserify, Webpack, Rollup, Closure), as well as a minified/optimized ambient `.js` which creates an ambient definition of your library, if that that makes sense for your library.  The two can be separate NPM packages.

Comment: Based on what I have read it seems like the closure will create the most compact / optimized bundles.  So if I compile the typescript to es6 (While relying on some node APIs), is closure all that is needed to make it run in the browser (Or are webpack and rollup also necessary?)?  I know that it's good to support multiple bundlers, but I"m just trying to figure out the minimal set of requirements to support closure ATM and whether closure is all that is needed.

Comment: The main thing that needs to happen in order to get it to run in the browser is to resolve all those `import` statements (or `require()` calls), which browsers don't support.  Closure, Webpack, Browserify, and Rollup are all capable of doing that.  If you actually want to support Closure, it's best to provide Closure type annotations, which are kind of redundant with TypeScript annotations, so it's a bit of extra work.  Closure provides relatively marginal improvements over e.g. Uglify these days so you have to figure out if the extra work (annotations) is worth it.

Comment: But the main two ways of doing things are still the same. You can provide a Node module which people can `import` or `require()`, and then they're responsible for doing optimization (e.g. Closure, Uglify) and resolving imports.  You can provide a pre-optimized, packed `.js` file.  And many packages provide both, giving users the option to choose either.

Comment: OK - I think I'm starting to get the big picture ... I really would like to keep it simple ... It appears that WebPack also does tree shaking, so es2015 module import / exports, webpack, and uglify seems like the simplest way to go ... thanks for all the feedback ...